# App Engine Backend Server Address (Insecure response)

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine

At the end it says:

`Change the backend host URL in main.js to https://backend-dot-[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com. Replace [PROJECT_ID] with your project ID.`

As an example my project ID is "project", does this mean I should set the URL to:

`https://backend-dot-project.appspot.com`
OR
`https://backend.project.appspot.com`

I've tried setting it to both, and I get an INSECURE_RESPONSE error in Chrome. I don't know what URL I need.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `https://backend-dot-project.appspot.com` is correct

Comment: You should just replace the brackets for your Project ID (not the project name, just to be clear). For example, if your Project ID is my-project-123, the result should be `https://backend-dot-my-project-123.appspot.com`